# web3-shh package will be deprecated in version 1.3.5 and will no longer be supported

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, web3js

My code as below, it is very brief and simple, only for test purpose.

```js
import React, { memo, useEffect } from "react";
import Web3 from "web3";

const AuctionDetail = (): JSX.Element => {
  const ether = window.ethereum;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof window.ethereum !== undefined) {
      ether.autoRefreshOnNetworkChange = false;

      const w = new Web3(ether);
      console.log(w);
    }
  }, [ether]);
  return (
    <>
      <div>Here Auction Detail</div>
    </>
  );
};

export default memo(AuctionDetail);
```

I don't know why got this alarm info, I even did nothing with 'web3-shh', 'web3-bzz'.

Per the tip, should I disconnect? How to do that?

```
MetaMask: The event 'close' is deprecated and may be removed in the future. Please use 'disconnect' instead.
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I read the link 'https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/issues/9301', but still not sure, what lead to this issue.